# QFileSystemWatcher not emitting directoryChanged signal

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I am trying to monitor a folder for changes but I can't get QFileSystemWatcher to work

Currently I've tried connecting the signal in 2 different ways but neither of them seem to work

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class FileSystemWatcherTest(QFileSystemWatcher):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.addPath("/Users/Alex/Desktop")
        print(self.directories())

        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("directoryChanged(const QString &)"), self, SLOT("self.changed(const QString &)")

    @pyqtSlot("const QString &")
    def changed(self, directory):
        print("Working")
```

and

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class FileSystemWatcherTest(QFileSystemWatcher):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.addPath("/Users/Alex/Desktop")
        print(self.directories())

        self.directoryChanged.connect(self.changed)

    def changed(self, directory):
        print("Working")
```

both times it seems to not connect any signal even though I am adding/removing files from the folder

Comment: Where is your code to instantiate the class?
Where is your `QApplication` call?

Comment: The first example is wrong in several ways. Do not use the old-style signal/slot syntax unless you know what you're doing. The second example is okay, and works fine for me. So obviously the errors must be in other code that you have not shown.